# Ubuntu install fails on Compaq evo510s

Tags: boot, usb, usb-drive

I have downloaded 32bit Ubuntu and installed it onto a stick using pendrivelinux. The computer I am trying to install Linux on refuses to boot from the USB. What I did next was to USB the hard drive and let pendrive linux install directly to it with a format first. That did not work so now I am left at the boot screen with the following messages.

```
Attempting Boot From Floppy Drive (A:)
Attempting Boot From CD-ROM
Attempting Boot From USB Device
Attempting Boot From Hard Drive (C:)

SYSLINUX 4.07 EDD 2013-07-25 Copyright (C) 1994-2013 H. Peter Anvin et al
: attempted DOS system call INT 21 0D00 F000101C
boot:
```

I pressed enter and get the following

```
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
boot:
```

Answer (score 1):

No matter what I did my compaq evo510s would not accept USB as a bootable drive it kept saying it was invalid media. I eventually did get Ubuntu installed on it by using another computer to do it.

I connected the Compaq's hard drive to another machine (one already running Ubuntu installed from USB), booted the USB and installed to the Compaq's drive. I replaced the HDD and now the Compaq is running Ubuntu!